# Common Xaml for all the page in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I want to make a xamlpage( or only xaml ) in which i have xaml controls . And i wanted to use it in multiple pages in Windows 8 app any idea is appreciated.

Comment: what kind of controls you want to share ?

Comment: @arun in case of user control i have to define it on each page..but i really don't want that. i want it like a some notification so whenever some update happen it just come in picture whatever the page is..

Comment: ok, you can use toast notifications, but they have limitation as user can turnoff toast notifications, so my idea is use base class which inherit Page class, and drive every page from that base class. Define control like popup in base and call it from child classes.

Comment: @arun can i do this in app.xaml make it static..what is your opinion..

Comment: no you can't as app.xaml inherit Application class, which is majorly use for navigation purpose and initilization

Comment: @Arun i am giving you an up as it helps me a lot..where i should go..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good starting point here would be to look at the LayoutAwarePage class in the standard Grid app template.  This class is a subclass of the Page type and includes a lot of standard functionality (e.g. handling orientation changes)

If you create something similar to LayoutAwarePage you can have a standard set of functionality in there that you can re-use across your app.  Be aware, though, that you will likely need to have some more logic on each actual derived page in order to make it work.  Also, and UI you want to paint on these pages would need to be coded explicitly in C# as there is no associate XAML with this class.

Answer (score 1):

you can begin something like this....here is your child classes,

```
        public sealed partial class ChildClass: ApplicationPageBase     
        {
            private void OnSomeEvent(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
            {
               base.IspopOpen = true;
            }
        }
```

Base class will be look like this

```
        public abstract class ApplicationPageBase : Page
        {
           private Popup settingsPopup;
           private bool _IsPopOpen;
           public bool IspopOpen { get;set; }
           public ApplicationPageBase()
            {
               InitiatePopUp();
            }
           void InitiatePopUp()
             {
                settingsPopup = new Popup();
                 //do some code for popup
             }
        }
```

**Note: This is just a work around**

Comment: this Applicationbase class can have associated xaml..like i am talking about page..can i inherit page directly..

Comment: yes you can unfortunately :)  add xaml as ControlTemplate to app.xaml in Application.Resources, and then you can access it in base page:

Template = (ControlTemplate)Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.Resources["GlobalControlKey"]

Comment: thanks..your ans is helpful..what i found is i need some break..:D